# install Ubuntu minor problem partions

Tags: 18.04, system-installation

[image: install alongside windows]
[image: select partitions]

Hello, I am trying to install Ubuntu alongside my windows 10, I have created a partition of 450GB and now not sure what to pick here,I want Ubuntu on my run alongside windows i.e each time PC loads i pick which one.

most questions use "something else" while installing.
My question is what should(recommended) size be for each?
*not sure if it matters i am installing from USB

Answer (score 0):

It seems straightforward to me: it depends on your usage.

If you know you will use Ubuntu more, you can allocate more space. There is no recommendation really, though I would recommend to allocate at least 20GB of space for any distribution.

Don't worry about selecting which OS to start when your PC boots, a program named GRUB will be installed automatically for you. Look it up if you want to customize it!